# What are these yellow bugs and should I be worried?

Tags: plant-health, insects, bugs

I took a close look at one of my plants, and saw all these tiny yellow bugs.

[image: Bugs.jpg]
They don't seem to be hurting the plant, but I thought I'd ask to make sure.

If it helps, this is in the San Francisco Bay Area.

Answer (score 4):

They look like [aphids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid) to me. Spraying the plant with neem oil or an insecticidal soap should help clear them up. You could also wipe down the plant before spraying it so you get rid of the bulk of the bugs quickly.

Comment: They are aphids, specifically Oleander or Milkweed Aphid - you can blast them off with the hose instead, but unless you use a systemic treatment, they may be back the next day, and the day after, and the day after that...